# Is there a way to disable the Facebook in-browser notifications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

Is there a way to disable the in-browser Facebook notifications (in the bottom left corner of the screen, see attached image)?

They seem to get queued in all open browser tabs. Meaning if I have multiple open Facebook tabs, I will see the same notification in each (even if I dismiss them in one). Which is rather annoying.

[image: annoying Facebook notifications]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using uBlock Origin (which is anyhow very recommended addon) and used it to block these pop-ups. This is how:

Once a pop-up pops-up:

1. Click on the add-on's icon.
2. Click on the picker icon on the buttom of the window that opens:

[image: picker icon]

3. Click on the pop-up you want to never show again (make sure you point the mouse pointer at a spot that selects all of the pop-up's rectangle.
4. A small window of the add-on will open up at the bottom right corner of your screen.
5. You can move the slides to select a bigger or smaller rectangle of the pop-up.
6. Click on "Create".

It will never show again if you selected all of the pop-up rectangle.

If it didn't work you can undo it. Search google for "How to Unblock a Web Page Element With uBlock Origin"

If you didn't understand the steps I explained above on how to block the pop-up element you can search google for "uBlock Origin how to remove any element from a page permanently"